# how write logging program python to 2 file?

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I use module logging in python to write log my program, i want log to 2 file in 2 other field,but when run program, 2 file log created and content log is same,  this code:

```
import threading
import traceback
import time
import logging
from logging import handlers

class Worker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        self.logger_error = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger_error.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        handler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='logworker/log', when='D', interval=1)
        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        handler_error = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='logjoberror/log', when='D', interval=1)
        handler_error.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        handler_error.setFormatter(formatter)

        self.logger.addHandler(handler)
        self.logger_error.addHandler(handler_error)

        try:
            self.log2 = threading.Thread(target=self.log2)
            self.log2.setDaemon
            self.log2.start()
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    def log1(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                self.logger.info('log to file 1 1111111111111')
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def log2(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)        
            try:
                self.logger_error.info('log to file 2 22222222')
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Worker()
    a.log1()

This content file log1:
2013-11-19 16:05:34,717 - log to file 2 22222222
2013-11-19 16:05:34,717 - log to file 1 1111111111111
2013-11-19 16:05:35,717 - log to file 2 22222222
2013-11-19 16:05:35,717 - log to file 1 1111111111111
2013-11-19 16:05:36,717 - log to file 1 1111111111111
2013-11-19 16:05:36,717 - log to file 2 22222222
2013-11-19 16:05:37,717 - log to file 1 1111111111111
```

This content file log2:

```
2013-11-19 16:05:34,717 - log to file 2 22222222
2013-11-19 16:05:34,717 - log to file 1 1111111111111
2013-11-19 16:05:35,717 - log to file 2 22222222
2013-11-19 16:05:35,717 - log to file 1 1111111111111
2013-11-19 16:05:36,717 - log to file 1 1111111111111
```

help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please read **15.7.1. Logger Objects** from

[Module logging](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#module-logging)

It says

> Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

That`s why your code has to behave like this.

Beside the way you used the module is not the cleanest one, for a POC this should fix it:

```
    handler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='logworker/log', when='D', interval=1)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    self.logger.addHandler(handler)

    handler_error = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='logjoberror/log', when='D', interval=1)
    handler_error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    handler_error.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger_error = logging.getLogger('handler_error')
    self.logger_error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    self.logger_error.addHandler(handler_error)
```

I hope that helped.